# Can you put a <center> tag before <body> tag in HTML?

Tags: html, tags

Recently in class I have been tasked with making a web page.
I made the page - I was expecting a high grade (it's nothing special but we're starting out in HTML, didn't even touch CSS yet), but to my surprise I failed the task.

Apparently, you're not supposed to put a `<center>` tag before a `<body>` tag.
My .html file looked something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>filler</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    
<center>
    <body>
    <p>filler</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it actually not allowed to put a  tag before a  tag? If so, what would be a better way to align it? (maybe body style?)

Comment: Don't use `<center>` at all. It's [obsolete now and not recommended to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). But to answer your question no, it can't be an ancestor of `<body>`

Comment: you can, but you shouldn't, also `<center>` is obsolete... use `body { text-align:center; }`

Answer (score 3):

As other said in comment, dont use [center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) anymore. Here how to center content inside body with [place-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items):

```css
 html, body { height: 100%; }

body { display: grid; place-items: center; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>filler</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <p>filler</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next step is to learn about `display: grid` and `display: flex` :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's CSS, right? We haven't done CSS yet, so there's no way my teacher would accept that haha

Thanks again!

Comment: @joystick but you should use CSS for this kind of task. HTML is meant to declare stuff in your page not to stylize it. Centering like coloring is the job of CSS. Teaching  `<center>`, `<blink>` or `marquee`  to beginners is a waste of time. If you really have to use `<center>`, follow [Michael Haddad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844711/1248177).

Answer (score 2):

you can, but you shouldn't, also `<center>` is obsolete... use `body { text-align:center; }`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, [`center` is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). But even if it wasn't, you should have put it *inside* the `body` element, and not the other way around:

```
<body>
    <center>
        ...
    </center>
</body>
```

[The body element represents the content of the document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element), where "content" is - broadly speaking - everything the user can actually see. This means that if the user can see it, it should probably be inside the `body` element. Since the point of the `center` element is to alter what the user sees, it belongs inside `body`.

However, there is a good reason `center` is obsolete: enhancing the separation between the *presentational structure* of a web page and its *design*. We use HTML to model what a web page consists of, and CSS to express how it should look. If you find yourself writing HTML with the intention of changing the *look* of your page - you are probably doing something wrong.

So to summarize: the `center` element is an HTML element that affects design, this is why it was made obsolete. And even if it wasn't obsolete, it should have been inside `body`.